# How to configure the connection to a ".sql" - database file in the ".env"-file of a laravel-project?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, mariadb

I've downloaded someones laravel-project and try to run it. There was also a '.sql'-file attached.

The '.env' -file was mentioned in the project's .gitignore-file, hence it wasn't included in the repository (which is the best practice, I recon). I copied this one into the project's root:
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example

I've configured the database-related section of this file like so:

- DB_CONNECTION=xampp
- DB_HOST=localhost
- DB_PORT=3306
- DB_DATABASE= my_own_db
- DB_USERNAME=root
- DB_PASSWORD=

(no password required)

I've run the command `php artisan key:generate` to add the encryption key to the ".env"-file, and tried the following steps to run the app:

1. I start the apache web server and mysql database using the **xampp-manager** (macOS)
2. I run the app using the command `php artisan serve`

The app itself loads, but it's empty since it doesn't  read the data. However, **phpMyAdmin** shows that the database and it's data is readable at:
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/sql.php?server=1&db=   [my_own_db] [name of the table]

Here's a screenshot of the settings:

[image: SQL Database settings shown in myPHPAdmin]

These are the db's privileges:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not import the SQL file in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DB_CONNECTION should still read mysql. That field is the driver of database connection. Xampp is a bundle of software for local web development, but your database looks to be a MariaDB. MariaDB is a fork of mysql and driver compatible.

DB_CONNECTION=mysql

Comment: I've tried that. Still, when I execute "php artisan serve", all that's shown at "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" is the app's loader/indicator, displaying a message that translates to "Please wait while loading".

Comment: Aer you still having issue's with this? Just saw that you commented. Try making sure sql is running properly by connecting to it locally with my sql workbench

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have an empty database.

Then check your database information in .env file. Make sure it connected to correct database.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=yourdbname
DB_USERNAME=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD=dbpass
```

If needed, run composer install or update

```
composer install
```

Then run key generate

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Then run migration

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

If the project have seeder, use:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

Then serve to run the localhost server

```
php artisan serve
```

If you are developing project using Laravel, I would suggest you to use Laragon instead of XAMPP

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Which kind of problem does this resolve? How does it ensure that any data from the SQL file is read?